# Check SQL Server table values against themselves

Tags: t-sql, levenshtein-distance

Imagine I had this table:

```
declare @tmpResults table ( intItemId int, strTitle nvarchar(100), intWeight float )

insert into @tmpResults values (1, 'Item One', 7)
insert into @tmpResults values (2, 'Item One v1', 6)
insert into @tmpResults values (3, 'Item Two', 6)
insert into @tmpResults values (4, 'Item Two v1', 7)
```

And a function, which we'll call fn_Lev that takes two strings, compares them to one another and returns the number of differences between them as an integer (i.e. the Levenshtein distance).

What's the most efficient way to query that table, check the fn_Lev value of each strTitle against all the other strTitles in the table and delete rows are similar to one another by a Levenshtein distance of 3, preferring to keeping higher intWeights?

So the after the delete, @tmpResults should contain

```
1   Item One    7
4   Item Two v1 7
```

I can think of ways to do this, but nothing that isn't horribly slow (i.e iterative). I'm sure there's a faster way?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT strvalue= CASE 
                WHEN t1.intweight >= t2.intweight THEN t1.strtitle 
                ELSE t2.strtitle 
              END, 
       dist = Fn_lev(t1.strtitle, t2.strtitle) 
FROM   @tmpResults AS t1 
       INNER JOIN @tmpResults AS t2 
         ON t1.intitemid < t2.intitemid 
WHERE  Fn_lev(t1.strtitle, t2.strtitle) = 3
```

This will perform a self join that will match each row only once. It will excluding matching a  row on itself or reverse of a previous match ie if A<->B is a match then B<->A isn't.

The case statement selects the highest weighted result

Comment: @MartinSmith would putting a where clause on a cross join with `t1.intitemid < t2.intitemid ` achieve the same effect. Might be worth profiling both to see which is best.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to include items that don't have duplicates?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not having a duplicate. can you give an example?

Comment: insert into @tmpResults values (5, 'Item Three', 9) - this item also needs to come out in the results. The suggested query only includes items that can be compared via fn_Lev

Comment: Why is that not comparable via fn_lev. I don't have an implementation to test with but is that not distance 5 from 'Item One' (3 changes One->Thr and 2 additions 'ee')

Comment: If you want to include a self comparison on each row, just change the join condition to `t1.intitemid <= t2.intitemid `. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood you correctly, you can use a cross join

```
SELECT t1.intItemId AS Id1, t2.intItemId AS Id2,  fn_Lev(t1.strTitle, t2.strTitle) AS Lev
FROM @tmpResults AS t1
CROSS JOIN @tmpResults AS t2
```

The cross join will give you the results of every combination of rows between the left and right side of the join (hence it doesn't need any ON clause, as it is matching everything to everything else). You can then use the result of the SELECT to choose which to delete.

Comment: My lord. This is what comes of being a self-taught developer. I can write a function that calculates Levenshtein distance but had no idea there was such a thing as a cross join! Thanks!

Comment: Not convinced that this will be the most efficient way as requested though in that it will be doing n squared comparisons.

Comment: Also, figuring out what to delete from those results isn't straightforward. Any other suggestions welcome while I work on it.